# How to pass data from a list view item to a dialog on taphold event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery mobile listview that has a button on it, for that button I listen out for the taphold event as follows:

```
$( "#myList" ).on( "taphold", "#myButton", self.tapholdHandler );
```

And in my tapholdHandler I open a dialog as follows:

```
self.tapholdHandler =  function( event ){
    $.mobile.changePage("#myDialog", {
        role: "dialog"
    });
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var text = $("#textarea").val();
    });
}
```

This opens a dialog I have set up in my HTML. Each item in my ListView has an ID number, I need to be able to access this ID number from the dialog, so that when the user presses the submit button from the dialog the text from the textarea gets appended to the ID.

So my question is how do I get the ID value from my ListView item when the taphold event is fired and how to pass it to my dialog?

EDIT: Here is my HTML markup:

My list:

```
<ul id="myList"  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-bind="foreach: myData" data-filter="true">
  <li>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a" data-bind="text: myID" id="idtest"></div>
  
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a
          data-role="button"
          id="denyButton"
          data-bind="click: $parent.clickToSubmit" >Submit</a>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And my dialog:

```
    <div data-role="page" data-rel="dialog" id="myDialog" data-theme="c" data-close-btn="right">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>Title holder</h1>
      </div>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" style="height:300px;" maxlength="200"></textarea>
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" id="submit">Submit</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I handle the click on the button so I need to know how to handle the taphold with data.

Comment: can you post a sample of your html markup?

Comment: Sure, I have just added it

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BKpTA/

Comment: Not quite, see - http://jsfiddle.net/BKpTA/3/ - I need to be able to get the random number value in each item

Comment: which random numbers? there are no changes in the fiddle except for `taphold` instead of `click`.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I must have forgot to update, try this - http://jsfiddle.net/BKpTA/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45932/discussion-between-omar-and-donal-rafferty)